How can I compare the elements of two lists (in terms of overall similarity and order) in R?
I have a list of the 'actual' top 25 authors and I want to compare this to lists of predicted top 25 authors (I have 5x repeats of the predicted list). I want to compare actual and predicted both in terms of proportion of the predicted authors that are the same as the 'actual' authors as well as the order of the lists. What is the best way to do this?
Example data below:
actual_authors <- list("Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Edward", "Fred")

predicted_authors <- list("Ian", "Liam", "Harry", "Toby", "Tom") 

Overall, the predicted list contains 40% percent of the actual list, however I also want to look at the order of the list - both Harry and Tom are in the predicted list but their location is not the same as in the actual list. It would be good to give a mean %similarity (after comparing actual to each predicted) and a p-value.
What is the best way to do this?

Are you asking about a specific implementation in R (off-topic here), or about ways to compute a similarity that addresses both "setwise overlap" and positioning (on-topic), or about significance testing (on-topic)? "Best" will be highly context-dependent.

Sorry, I am new to this. I am looking to as you say test for both setwise overlap and positioning, and ideally give an idea of the significance of the result as well. I would like to implement the tests in R (but can find out how to do that once I know which test to use).

Thank you, that helps. What do you mean by "I have 5x repeats of the predicted list"?

Compared to the usual measures precision and recall, or combinations thereof, whcih are based on "hit or miss", the measure "Normalized Discounted Cumulative Gain" (NDCG) also takes the ranking of the retrieved items into account. This might exactly be what you are looking for.

@StephanKolassa I have run the algorithm 5x to generate 5 lists - predicted using a kind of random surfer model -  (each to compare to the manually generated list)

A simple approach would be:

First, calculate a distance $d_1$ between your prediction and the actual that only depends on the "setwise overlap": if you are interested in the top $n$ predictions and actuals, you could calculate one minus the proportion of the top $n$ actuals that are also among the top $n$ predicted authors. This gives you a number between $0$ and $1$.
Next, if there is overlap between the two lists, calculate a notion of distance between the positions of elements that appear in both lists. For instance, you could use the mean of the average distance between the positions of an author on the predicted vs. the actual order. Some scaling by the number of overlaps would be in order: if you have only a single overlap, its distance can be between $0$ and $n-1$, but if you have two overlaps, the average distance can be no larger than $n-2$. Use a "reasonable" number if there is no overlap.
Finally, take a weighted combination of the two distances, like a simple weighted average. The weighting should reflect how important the two dimensions are to you. How much worse is it to have zero overlap than to have full overlap, but in a random order?

I am not going into how to calculate a $p$ value here, because that would require some more information on what your null hypothesis is, against what alternative you would want to test, possibly on how large your population is. If you want to test your selection algorithm to be better ("better" as operationalized by a distance like the one here) than blind chance, then having a single hit anywhere in your top $n$ list might be significant if your population of authors to draw from is large. If you are interested in this, then I would recommend you play around with your distance measures and then open a new question, linking back to this one for context.
